# Where do you put your unit test?

Tags: unit-testing

I have found several conventions to housekeeping unit tests in a project and
I'm not sure which approach would be suitable for our next PHP project. I am
trying to find the best convention to encourage easy development and
accessibility of the tests when reviewing the source code. I would be very
interested in your experience/opinion regarding each:

1. One folder for productive code, another for unit tests: This separates
   unit tests from the logic files of the project. This separation of
   concerns is as much a nuisance as it is an advantage: Someone looking into
   the source code of the project will - so  I suppose - either browse the
   implementation or the unit tests (or more commonly: the implementation
   only). The advantage of unit tests being another viewpoint to your classes
   is lost - those two viewpoints are just too far apart IMO.
2. Annotated test methods: Any modern unit testing framework I know allows
   developers to create dedicated test methods, annotating them (*@test*) and
   embedding them in the project code. The big drawback I see here is that
   the project files get cluttered. Even if these methods are separated
   using a comment header (like *UNIT TESTS below this line*) it just bloats
   the class unnecessarily.
3. Test files within the same folders as the implementation files: Our file
   naming convention dictates that PHP files containing classes (one class
   per file) should end with *.class.php*. I could imagine that putting unit
   tests regarding a class file into another one ending on *.test.php* would
   render the tests much more present to other developers without tainting
   the class. Although it bloats the project folders, instead of the
   implementation files, this is my favorite so far, but I have my doubts: I
   would think others have come up with this already, and discarded this
   option for some reason (i.e. I have not seen a java project with the files
   *Foo.java* and *FooTest.java* within the same folder.) Maybe it's because
   java developers make heavier use of IDEs that allow them easier access to
   the tests, whereas in PHP no big editors have emerged (like eclipse for
   java) - many devs I know use vim/emacs or similar editors with little
   support for PHP development per se.

What is your experience with any of these unit test placements? Do you have
another convention I haven't listed here? Or am I just overrating unit test
accessibility to reviewers?

Answer (score 27):

I favour keeping unit-tests in separate source files in the same directory as production code (#3).

Unit tests are not second-class citizens, their code must maintained and refactored just like production code. If you keep your unit tests in a separate directory, the next developer to change your production code may miss that there are unit tests for it and fail to maintain the tests.

In C++, I tend to have three files per class:

```
MyClass.h
MyClass.cpp
t_MyClass.cpp
```

If you're using Vim, then my [toggle_unit_tests](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2500) plug-in for toggling between source and unit test files may prove useful.

Comment: if the developer misses it, why aren't they to blame. Every developer should be concerned with unit tests even if they aren't directly visible.

Comment: @Crt: Blame hasn't proven to be a useful facet of any engineering team I've been a part of. I'd rather set future developers up for success by making concerns obvious so that they can spend their time meeting business requirements.

Comment: good point. I think I should have used the word "responsibility". Would you agree that devs should feel a responsibility to make sure their code is tested.

Comment: @Crt: I think my answer to this is "it depends". I agree in principle, but I can think of some situations where I have preferred to eschew unit testing with a focus on restoring service to production systems.

Answer (score 9):

The current best practice is to separate the unit tests into their own directory, #1. All of the "convention over configuration" systems do it like this, eg. Maven, Rails, etc.

I think your alternatives are interesting and valid, and the tool support is certainly there to support them. But it's just not that popular (as far as I know). Some people object to having tests interspersed with production code. But it makes sense to me that if you always write unit tests, that they be located right with your code. It just seems simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I always go for #1. While it's nice that they are close together. My reasons are as followed:

- I feel there's a difference between the core codebase and the unittests. I need a real separation.
- End-users rarely need to look at unittests. They are just interested in the API. While it's nice that unittests provide a separate view on the code, in practice I feel it won't be used to understand it better. (more descriptive documentation + examples do).
- Because end-users rarely need unittests, I don't want to confuse them with more files and/or methods.
- My coding standards are not half as strict for unittests as they are for the core library. This is maybe just my opinion, but I don't care as much for coding standards in my tests.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I disagree with "End-users rarely need to look at unittests". The first thing I do to understand a new code base is look at how the unit tests are using the code, classes and function.

Comment: You are not confusing end users, you are actually empowering them by reminding them to treat the tests as first class citizens.

Comment: @BasilMusa, well. This answer is 10 years old. However, I still more or less feel the same. Mostly subjective I guess though.